# Why does AbstractCollection not implement size()?

Tags: java, collections, size

When sub-classing `AbstractCollection`, I must still implement `size()`, even though (I believe) there is a <s>reasonable</s> correct (though non-performant) default implementation:

```
public int size() {
    int count = 0;

    for (Iterator<E> i = iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
        i.next();
        count++
    }

    return count;
}
```

Why did the designers not include a default implementation of `size()`? Were they trying to force developers to consciously think about this method, hopefully causing the developer to offer an implementation that performs better than the default?

Comment: It's not very reasonable implementation for ArrayList for example. That's probably why they did not implement it by default it to avoid hidden traps.

Comment: @denis.solonenko: I meant that it's reasonable *from a correctness perspective*. I agree with you, it is **not** reasonable from a *performance* perspective.

Comment: there is no single case I know of, the method won't be overridden. CLQ is close to that, though, yet the impl is faster. To put it simply: a useless piece of code that must be overridden each time AND it can throw ConcurrentModificationException, what do you in such a case?

Comment: @bestsss: I agree. I almost always provide better-than-O(N) implementations. I was just curious to see what other reasons people could think up. :)

Comment: @bestsss: FYI: One example of a collection whose `size()` must be O(N) is a *filtered* collection (that is, a *view* of another collection that only sees certain elements). This can be seen in Guava's [`Collections2.filter`](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/source/browse/trunk/guava/src/com/google/common/collect/Collections2.java) method (see the `FilteredCollection` inner class).

Comment: @Adam, I already mentioned CLQ (ConcurrentLinkedQueue), it's O(n). Most concurrent structures can have O(n) for size, that's normal. ConcurrentSkipListMap is similar, any collections derived from will have similar downsides. I dont use guava. Yet, after proxying the entire collection framework for a JDO impl, I have an idea how to filter (and how the framework performs internally). Even in such case like guava size can be cached when (if) possible.

Comment: @Adam, btw you need to bail out like `if (++count==Integer.MAX_VALUE) return count;` instead just `count++`

Comment: @bestsss: Thanks for the heads-up. :) I was aware of that, but I chose to leave it out so that the ultimate intention of the code wasn't muddied (considering most people deal with collections of fewer than `Integer.MAX_VALUE` elements).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I suspect your last sentence is the real reason. When subclassing an abstract class it's sometimes tempting to only override the abstract methods. I would expect almost *every* implementation to have a better implementation than just iterating - so if you *want* pretty much everyone to override a method, it's probably a good idea not to provide a base (slow) implementation. It just reduces chances of screwing up :)

Comment: actually the iteration can throw a `ConcurrentModifcationException`, which is not acceptable for `size()`

Comment: @bestsss: Well, it's a RuntimeException... if a collection isn't documented to be thread-safe (which is the only place this could have a problem) then I don't think it's awful for size() to throw ConcurrentModificationException.

Comment: all the exceptions of the collection framework are runtime ones  but they are documented (and that incl. the likes of NPE, ClassCastException, ArrayStoreException).

Comment: @bestsss: Then maybe `size()` *should* actually be documented to potentially throw this. Why should it be impossible to have a collection which requires multiple operations to compute the size?

Comment: then isEmpty() too and so on. basically everything. My understanding is that size() works on the best-effort basis, though.

Answer (score 5):

While this is a *possible* default implementation, it is not necessarily a good one (or even a sane one).

In **almost all** general-purpose `Collection` implementation there's a O(1) way to find out the size. Usually by simply querying a simple field.

This should be the implementation. In the very rare cases where this is not the case, the implementation could still fall back to your example code (or implement it differently).

Answer (score 1):

I support your theory: maybe implementers are just forced to implement a good (`O(1)` if possible) implementation for `size()`, because

- the method is used quite often
- if we program against interfaces, we don't know the actual collection type
- A default (or bad) implementation may kill performance unexpectedly

Answer (score 1):

For some kinds of list, your proposed default implementation is harmful.  I'm thinking of lazy lists, or lists that result in a very large in-memory data structure when iterated.

In the infinite lazy list case, your proposed default implementation is plainly incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, since both the `add` and `remove` operations have a return value that indicates whether the operation resulted in a change of the size of the collection, you could implement an event better `size` method by keeping track of adds and removes in most cases.