# Why doesn't AbstractCollection implement iterator()?

Tags: java, collections

From : [Collections Framework](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/collections/Collection.html)

"the AbstractCollection class provides implementations for all the methods, except for the iterator() and size() methods, which are implemented in the appropriate subclass"

Could anyone make clear the reason why no default behavior for iterator() ?
I could see why size () is not default from this question : [Why does AbstractCollection not implement size()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6676512/why-does-abstractcollection-not-implement-size)

Answer (score 6):

What would it do?

The `iterator()` method is how the derived class actually provides the data.
All of the methods that `AbstractCollection` implements simply perform the appropriate logic using the data provided by the actual implementation in `size()` and `iterator()`.

Answer (score 2):

The `AbstractCollection` does not know of how the data is stored, so there are two choices for the `iterator()` implementation:

- Make it an abstract method, or
- Throw `UnsupportedOperationException` the way it does for many other methods, such as `add` or `remove`.

Only the first solution makes sense: collections must allow at least reading, while writing may be optional.

Answer (score 0):

Think of three different collections:  a list based on an array, a linked list, and let's say sorted list based on a tree.  An iterator for the array based collection would need to know who to access each element based on it's indexed location.  An iterator for a linked list would need to know how to traverse the links between elements.  And an iterator for a tree-based collection would need to know how to traverse a tree (for example breadth-first or depth-first).  You can see that all these behaviors are very different and are implementation specific.